# js аккордеон без id

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать аккордеон где при нажатии на `.item-btn` у класса `.item-content` будет добавляться или убираться класс `.item-content--active`. Это работать должно **без id**.

У меня получилось только при нажатии на `.item`, но это не подходит. Надо чтобы только при нажатии на `.item-btn` у класса `.item-content` будет добавляться или убираться класс `.item-content--active`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((event) =>
  event.addEventListener('click', () => {
    event.querySelector('.item-content').classList.toggle('item-content--active');
  })
);
```

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item-btn {
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}

.item-content--active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-btn">
    111
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    222
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-btn">
    111
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    222
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-btn">
    111
  </div>
  <div class="item-content">
    222
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `event` - плохое имя для переменной и вносит много путаницы, не используй его

Comment: что мешает вместо `event.addEventListener('click'` писать `event.querySelector('.item-btn').addEventListener('click'` - как ты это делаешь внутри  обработчика?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `element.closest`, чтобы получить родительский элемент и ищи контент внутри него уже.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item-btn').forEach((btn) =>
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btn
          .closest('.item')
          .querySelector('.item-content')
          .classList
          .toggle('item-content--active');
    } )  
);
```